# Event space question, probability.

Tags: probability

Let F be a field of subsets of the set Omega. Suppose that A and B are in F. Show that A\B and A intersection B are also in F.

How do I start with this one?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, write each of them in terms of unions and set-conplements, using de Morgan's Laws:

$$A\setminus B = A\cap B^c = (A^c \cup B)^c.$$

$$A\cap B = (A^c \cup B^c)^c.$$

You can then use the field axioms to show they belong to $F$.